# Why downloading the same web page twice with wget results in two files which differ?

Tags: wget, diff

I'm trying to write a script that notifies me when a static web page has changed. To do it, I'm using `wget` to download the web page, and `diff` to check whether it has changed or not. I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS virtual machine. Here is the example:

```
$ wget --quiet https://twiki.di.uniroma1.it/twiki/view/Reti_Avanzate/InternetOfThings2021 -O file1
$ wget --quiet https://twiki.di.uniroma1.it/twiki/view/Reti_Avanzate/InternetOfThings2021 -O file2
$ diff -q file1 file2
Files file1 and file2 differ
```

As you can see, `diff` reports differences between the two files. Why? Even if I try to compare them with `diff -y` they look the same for me.

**UPDATE**

Looking for differences with `git diff --color-words -- file1 file2` gave the following result:

[image: Differences]

Apparently, there's a field in which the timestamp is added, and in one of the two files there's a `<!--GENERATED_HEADERS-->` which is absent in the other.

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried a different viewer? `git diff --color-words -- file1 file2` might be more illustrative than a line-based view.

Comment: @ojdo thank you, updated

Comment: wow, that's a weird piece of software. There's a bunch of links there that look like `<a href="/twiki/..." class="twikiLink">`, and the `href` and `class` attributes are in the opposite order in another between two downloads I got. You could use some tool to just extract the text content (but whitespace might still be a problem). Or, since it looks to be a wiki with version control, look at the revision number/date. It says "Topic revision: r170 - 2021-05-22" at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using w3m with `-dump` option that ignores tags while rendering the page.

```
$ w3m -dump  https://twiki.di.uniroma1.it/twiki/view/Reti_Avanzate/InternetOfThings2021 > file1
$ w3m -dump  https://twiki.di.uniroma1.it/twiki/view/Reti_Avanzate/InternetOfThings2021 > file2
$ if cmp -s file1 file2; then echo "Files are not different"; fi
  Files are not different                                                              
$
```

Answer (score 2):

One more "answer" not on how to solve this, but what causes this: the used version of (apparently) TiddlyWiki seems to generate its output *with random tag order* in HTML elements. Examples:

```
--- file1
+++ file2
@@ -703,881 +703,881 @@
[...]
-<td valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="twikiTableCol2" align="left"> r1 </td>
[...]
+<td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="twikiTableCol2" align="left" valign="top"> r1 </td>
[...]
```

This repeats for attributes in tables, images, links.